# Python how read this json simil string

Tags: python, json

Please how print this line:

```
{"1":{"home":"001","street":"Wolrd1","cap":0},"2":{"home":"002","street":"Wolrd2","cap":0},"3":{....}}
```

in this format:

```
{"home":"001","street":"Wolrd1","cap":0}
{"home":"002","street":"Wolrd2","cap":0}
{....}}
```

with this code:

```
import json
jsonData = '{"1":{"home":"001","street":"Wolrd1","cap":0},"2":{"home":"002","street":"Wolrd2","cap":0},"3":{....}}'
jsonToPython = json.loads(jsonData)

for x in jsonToPython:
    print x
```

print is:
1
2
3

Comment: `for x in jsonToPython.values(): print(x)`

Comment: Based on `print x`, I think you are using python 2.x. You should use 3.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON data gets converted into a dictionary when using the `json.loads()` method, where the *keys* are 1, 2, 3 etc, and the *values* are dictionaries as well (e.g.: `{"home":"001","street":"Wolrd1","cap":0}`).
The only modification you need is to use the `.values()` method in the for loop:

```
import json
jsonData = '{"1":{"home":"001","street":"Wolrd1","cap":0},"2":{"home":"002","street":"Wolrd2","cap":0},"3":{....}}'
jsonToPython = json.loads(jsonData)

jsonToPython = json.loads(jsonData)

for x in jsonToPython.values():
    print x
```